# I need to keep the modal from being closed by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

Any Ideas?

I tried inserting `....({ .....,...., close:false,....})` and nothing.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I will close the modal window when satisfied with `$.modal.close();`

Comment: Please add more code to your question.

Comment: Could you show the actual code you've tried? The ellipsis is mysterious, and such, but not helpful for us trying to help you.

Comment: 1. What version of SimpleModal are you using. 2) What are you expecting to happen. 3) What does "and nothing" mean...what is happening? 4. I tested with the "basic" demo and it worked as expected.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for trying to help. Let me try to explain myself:

the content inside of the ellipsis really does not matter here ... I was just trying to say that I have other options in the modal displaying string. EVERYTHING WORKS FINE with the display.

I confess that, to date, I NEVER needed to use either onClose, onShow, onOpen, .... The maximum I have used is just css: { } inside of the options parenthesis.
//// continue ....

Comment: Anywho: what I was thinking of doing and would hope I could solve the puzzle is:

I display a tinyMCE screen in my modal (everything working fantastic ... no bugs at all). However, I want to show multiple overlays (ah hah ... many of this question around stackoverflow regarding that). 

I can manage the overlays without any problem. I have plenty of solutions for that. HOWEVER, and here is where help would be appreciated:

In this specific handling, I would like to make sure the user CANNOT close the modal at all. Neither by pressing escape; neither by pressing my close button ....

Comment: When I finish all the processing that I want, (overlaying if necessary, etc, etc, ) and satisfied with the results, then my function (my javascript function) will close the modal by issuing a $.modal.close().

I have defended the thesis that only the "creator" understand his/her own "creation". So, don't feel disappointed if I cannot explain myself but, please, throw in your 2c........

TIA

Comment: ..


I am using simpleModal version 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you call a modal window as you have indicated `{close:false}`, the following will happen:

- The closeHTML will not be displayed
- The user cannot click the overlay to close the dialog
- The user cannot press ESC to close the dialog

If you have a button/link in your code with the `simplemodal-close` class, the user will still be able to press that to close the dialog.

So, based on the information you have provided, if you are using `{close:false}`, the only other way possible for a user to close the dialog is if *you* have provided a way for them to. As such, you need to hide, disable, or remove the `simplemodal-close` class until you are ready for them to close the dialog.

Comment: Thank you .... I will try that again. just to clarify, as I am a code-borrower, that would be:

$('#myDiv').modal({ ..., css: { }, close:false }) or
$('#myDiv').modal({ ..., css: { } }, {close:false} )

the close:false stands between it's own pair of brackets or within the modal options brackets? Yes, I am slow ... sorry and thanks.

Comment: It would be the first that you mentioned: $('#myDiv').modal({ ..., css: { }, close:false })